# Error: missing 2 required positional arguments

Tags: python, arguments

first of all I apologize as I know this is a basic question and I tried to find clues from other similar questions to find an answer but I haven't managed to solve my problem so far.

The error appeared in the last block of code below, where I tried adding a functionality to restart the program so the user can keep playing.

The error is "user_win() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'player' and 'opponent'"

--

Code is:

```
import random

def play():
    user = input("Enter 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors': ").lower()
    computer = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])
    return '\nThe computer randomly entered "{}".'.format(computer)

def user_win(player, opponent):
    if (player == 'rock' and opponent =='scissors') or (player == 'scissors' and opponent == 'paper') or (player == 'paper' and opponent == 'rock'):
        return 'Game result: you won!\n',
    elif player == opponent:
        return 'Game result: it\'s a tie!\n',
    elif player is not 'rock' or 'paper' or 'scissors':
        return 'Oops, enter a correct word.',
    else:
        return 'Game result: you lost!',

def script():
    print(play())
    print(user_win())
    restart = input("Would you like to try again?")
    if restart == "yes":
        print(script())
    if restart == "no":
        print("Thank you for playing.")
```

I tried entering `print(user_win(player, opponent))` inside `def script()` and then I got the error that "player" and "opponent" are not defined. So I tried defining these variables above `def script()` but I didn't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just *return the user and computer input* from `play()` and pass to `user_win(player, opponent)` also updated `elif player not in ['rock','paper','scissors']:`

**Code:**

```
import random

def play():
    user = input("Enter 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors': ").lower()
    computer = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])
    print('\nThe computer randomly entered "{}".'.format(computer))
    return user, computer
def user_win(player, opponent):
    if (player == 'rock' and opponent =='scissors') or (player == 'scissors' and opponent == 'paper') or (player == 'paper' and opponent == 'rock'):
        return 'Game result: you won!\n'
    elif player == opponent:
        return 'Game result: it\'s a tie!\n'
    
    elif player not in ['rock','paper','scissors']:
        return 'Oops, enter a correct word.'
    else:
        return 'Game result: you lost!'

def script():
    player, opponent = play()

    print(user_win(player,opponent))
    restart = input("Would you like to try again?")
    if restart == "yes":
        print(script())
    if restart == "no":
        print("Thank you for playing.")
        
script()
```

**Result:**

```
Enter 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors': rock

The computer randomly entered "paper".
Game result: you lost!
Would you like to try again?yes
Enter 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors': paper

The computer randomly entered "scissors".
Game result: you lost!
Would you like to try again?
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just call `user_win(user, computer)` from `play()` since play is where each player's moves are defined.

Answer (score 0):

In this section of your code below, when you call user_win(), you're not passing the arguments for player and opponent so you're getting this error.

```
def script():
    print(play())
    print(user_win())
```

instead, you could do this:

```
#modify the play section to return the choices
def play():
    user = input("Enter 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors': ").lower()
    computer = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])
    return [computer,computer]

def script():
    print(user_win(play()[0],play()[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

#Friend you haven't passed any arguments in user_win you that's why you are getting #the error.

## Here are some modifications in your code, now you can easily play your game.

import random

def user_win(player, opponent):

```
if (player == 'rock' and opponent == 'scissors') or (player == 'scissors' and opponent == 'paper') or (
        player == 'paper' and opponent == 'rock'):
    
    return 'Game result: you won!\n'

elif player == opponent:
    
    return 'Game result: it\'s a tie!\n'

elif player != 'rock' or player != 'paper' or player != 'scissors':
    
    return 'Oops, You lose.'

else:
    
    return 'You entered a wrong word !'
```

def script():

```
user = input("Enter 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors': ").lower()

computer = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])

print(f"'\nThe computer randomly entered : {computer} ")

print(user_win(user, computer))

restart = input("Would you like to try again? write yes(y)/ no(n) : ")

if restart == "yes" or restart == "y":
    
    print(script())
    
elif restart == "no" or restart == "n":
    
    print("Thank you for playing.")
    
    exit()
```

if **name** == '**main**':

```
script()
```

Comment: You're always welcome ! If there is any suggestion related to my code then you shall give me so that I can improve my coding skills.